# Want to keep running the exchange migration code after closing the web browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, process, background, exchange-server

I have asp.net Mvc application in which I am migrating mails from one exchange server to another , now I want to keep running migration process and don't want to keep open browser means when user closes browser process must be running at the back and after opening the browser user can check the progress of migration.
Can anyone help me in this, how to achieve this task using asp.net Mvc 4 c# or using any other service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the low amount of information in your question, I can only answer concisely.

- When the user triggers the migration (i.e. sends the request to MVC), you'll have to trigger the migration in a different thread.
- Make sure that the different thread has access to a globally accessible variable, e.g. `bool MigrationIsRunning`. Your migration will set this to `true` when starting, and back to `false` when completed (by success, or by error. Either way).
- When your user returns to the migration page, have your Controller method check the value of `MigrationIsRunning` (the variable from the previous step), and return the correct feedback to the user.

Note: instead of a bool, you could use a custom class that shows more detail. I'm not sure what your users need to know when the migration's running.

Note 2: If your entire application should be inaccessible during the migration, you're better off with placing step 3 either in your Masterpage, or Global.asax, so you have full coverage of your web application instead of a single page.

Comment: Thank you, I think migrationis running  method would work, and yes user want more details of how much progress is done right now when he visited back the page, so can you help me in how to show Jquery progress bar when user access that page again

Comment: That's a different question completely. The jQuery progress bar is not so much the problem. I suggest looking into the threading and sharing an object between the migration thread and the normal web requests; make sure you have the needed data. Then you can start visualizing that data.